# how i disable listview one time if i click on item of list view?

Tags: java, android

if i click on item of listview  the setOnItemClickListener make the listview Empty  in the same time  addTextChangedListener  searche in the database and add anothore products in listview.

```
namechange.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) { }
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                ArrayList<String> arrList = new ArrayList<>();
                if ((namechange.getText().toString()).equals("") ) {
                    arrList.clear();
                    final ArrayAdapter Adapter = new ArrayAdapter(MapsActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrList);
                    list.setAdapter(Adapter);
                    Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else {

                    SenderReceiver sr = new SenderReceiver(MapsActivity.this, url, namechange.getText().toString(),list);
                    sr.execute();

                    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                            String adapt = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
                            namechange.setText(adapt);
                            ArrayList<String> arrList = new ArrayList<>();
                            arrList.clear();
                            final ArrayAdapter Adapter = new ArrayAdapter(MapsActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrList);
                            list.setAdapter(Adapter);
                            Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                        }
                    });
                } }
```

Comment: Hi @DJAMEL , can you tell me what you want to achieve? , I don't get why you want to re-init click listener every time text changes, you should create your adapter outside of text change listener and only add or clear ArrayList and notify for change.

Comment: Thanks the problem has been solved

Comment: great if answer helped please marked it as solved and upvote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to take out your adapterList logic and click logic outside of TextChangeLogic and instead of onTextChanged callback use `afterTextChanged`

```
        final ArrayList<String> dataList = new ArrayList();
        final ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(MapsActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,dataList);
        list.setAdapter(Adapter);

        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                String item = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
                namechange.setText(item);
                dataList.clear();
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });


        nameChange.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(editable.toString())) {
                    dataList.clear();
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }else{
                    SenderReceiver sr = new SenderReceiver(MapsActivity.this, url, namechange.getText().toString(),list);
                    sr.execute();
                }
            }
        }
```